# Why do I have to compile with `-static`?

Tags: assembly, gcc, linker, x86-64, nasm

I have the following assembly code

```
        global   main 
        extern   println
    
        section  .text
    
main:
        mov rdi, message
        call     println
        ret

message:
        db "Hello, world!", 0
```

I am linking it with some C code

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void println(char *line) {
    puts(line);
}
```

I run the following commands to compile and link these two programs

```bash
nasm -f elf64 helloWorld.asm -o helloWorld.asm.o
gcc -c helloWorld.c -o helloWorld.c.o
gcc -static helloWorld.c.o helloWorld.asm.o -o helloWorld
```

then I run my finished program with

```
./helloWorld
```

If I remove `-static` from the `gcc` options, I get a seg-fault! Why is this??

Comment: If you 16-byte align the stack in `main` by making the first instruction `push rbp` and do a `pop rbp` right before the `ret`, what happens? As well you should zero out `al` before calling a variadic function like printf when there are no XMM registers being used to pass things like floats/doubles etc. `xor eax, eax` will zero out RAX(and AL).

Comment: @MichaelPetch: `println` is not variadic, and itself only uses `puts` not `printf` so there's no need to set AL.  It seems the dynamic-library build of glibc ended up with different code-gen than the static `libc.a`, with puts (and the internal stdio functions it calls) only depending on RSP%16==0 before a `call` in `libc.so.6`

Comment: @PeterCordes : Sorry I thought it was `printf` lol. So ignore the AL comment. You may have noticed I said `printf` in my comment which would be a hint at my gaff.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Yeah, and I had a different brain fart at first: I thought it was going to be [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43367427) 32-bit absolute addressing, but no, that would be a link error not a segfault.  NASM assembles `mov rdi, message` to `mov r64, imm64`, and GCC's CRT code for PIE executables does do runtime fixups (text relocations) on 64-bit absolute addresses.  Code like this does get a correct address into a register as long as you aren't writing your own `_start` and linking with `-static-pie`